# type error = assignment to constant variable react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const [todos , set_todos] = useState([''])
  const [input , set_input] = useState('')
  const new_todo = (event) =>{
    set_todos = ([...todos,input]);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <h1>hello world</h1>
      let input = <input value={input} onChange={event=> set_input(event.target.value)}/>
      
      <button onClick ={new_todo}>add todo</button>
      <ul>
        {todos.map(todo =>(
          <li>{todo}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      
    </>
  )
}
```

**the error is in 7th line of the code**

i am a totally new beginner so it would be helpful if you explain it to me

Comment: why yu declare `let input = <input ...` in return?

Comment: You are trying to override the const value, that is causing the issue

Comment: Please explain your use-case

Comment: remove equal operator on line 7 => set_todos([...todos,input]);

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update your state (that is an array) in react hooks, you should try like this :

```
  const new_todo = (input) => set_todos(oldState => [...oldState,input])
```

with this code, you will not see any error but I have some offer for your code that make it better:

- put your inputs such as input and buttons in the form tag
- use variable declarations outside of return ( let return be for HTML tag and its better to use your logics outside of return ) make it easier to read

and I think your code can be like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const [todos , set_todos] = useState([''])
  const submitTask = (e) =>{

    // Calling preventDefault() during any stage of event flow cancels the event,
    // meaning that any default action normally taken by the implementation
    // as a result of the event will not occur
    e.preventDefault(); 

    const { taskInput } = e.target; // get your input by name

    // assign input value to your state
    set_todos(oldState => [...oldState, taskInput.value ]) 
  }
  return (
    <>
      <h1>hello world</h1>
      <form onSubmit={submitTask}>
        <input name="taskInput" />
        <button type="submit">add todo</button>
      </form>

      <ul>
        {todos.map(todo =>(
          <li>{todo}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>

    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `set_todos` like below:

```
set_todos([...todos, input]);
```

Because `set_todos` is a function. You can find the State Hook's usage in [Introducing Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).